# Nested table header display values accordingly

Tags: html-table

I have nested table header and i'm working with the values, the value that im trying to set is setting outside to the html table. I don't know how to put values according their cells.

This is what i have tried so far,

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 30%;
}

tr, th, td {
  border:1px solid black
}
span{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="4">DEP'T</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="4">Trainee L-Leader</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>REG</td>
    <td>PROBI</td>
    <td>SEAS'L</td>
    <td>
    <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
    <th colspan="4">RANK</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>3B</td>
    <td>3A</td>
    <td>2A</td>
    <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    </table></td>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>COIL</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is what i'm trying to do and expected output.

```
       |--------------------------------------------------------|
       |          |                                             |
       |          |               TRAINEE L-LEADER              |
       |   DEPT   |---------------------------------------------|
       |          | REG |  PROBI  |  SEAS'L  |       RANK       |
       |          |     |         |          |------------------|
       |          |     |         |          | 3B | 3A | 2A | 1 |
       |--------------------------------------------------------|
       |   COIL   |  2  |    0    |    1     | 3  | 0  | 3  | 1 |
       |--------------------------------------------------------|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach to this is to not try to embed one table inside another, as that can make things more complicated.

Instead, I count how many overall rows and columns there are - in this case: 4 rows and 8 columns.

Then I create one row at a time:

In the first row: The first cell containing `DEPT` occupies 1 column, and 3 rows. The next cell occupies 7 columns and 1 row. Therefore we need this:

```html
<tr>
    <th rowspan="3">DEP'T</th>
    <th colspan="7">Trainee L-Leader</th>
</tr>
```

For the second row, we have already accounted for the first cell (from the `DEPT` data). The next 3 cells `REG`, `PROBI` and `SEAS'L` all occupy 2 rows. The final cell `RANK` occupies 4 columns. Therefore we need this:

```html
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2">REG</td>
    <td rowspan="2">PROBI</td>
    <td rowspan="2">SEAS'L</td>
    <th colspan="4">RANK</th>
</tr>
```

...and so on.

Note how the third row starts with `3B` - because the first 4 cells in row 3 have already been filled data we defined in the previous rows.

Overall, this approach just requires careful counting, starting from the top left cell and creating one row at a time.

The end result (with some CSS styling) is:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Flexbox Demo</title>

  <style>
    table {
      font-family: arial, sans-serif;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 30%;
    }
    
    .center-align {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    tr, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      padding: 5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>


  <table>
    <thead class="center-align">

      <tr>
        <th rowspan="3">DEP'T</th>
        <th colspan="7">Trainee L-Leader</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">REG</td>
        <td rowspan="2">PROBI</td>
        <td rowspan="2">SEAS'L</td>
        <th colspan="4">RANK</th>
      </tr>


      <tr>
        <td>3B</td>
        <td>3A</td>
        <td>2A</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>COIL</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>





</body>

</html>
```

---

You may need or want to make some additional adjustments for styling. You should be able to do that with more CSS - and also maybe by choosing where you want to use `<th>` tags (for bold) and where you want to use `<td>` tags.